# Azure DevOps build Artifacts not getting generated in .Net web app

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, artifact

I am building the application through Azure DevOps(VSTS) pipeline. This is the build pipeline parameters being used:

[image: Build parameters]

These are the Publish Artifact parameters:

[image: Publish Artifact parameters]

Initially I was using the "Copy file task" but then got to know that this task is used only in .net desktop based application and not in web based app so I have disabled this task.
The default values being used for two variables are:

> BuildConfiguration = release 
>   BuildPlatform = any CPU

After building the application, it shows build succeeded and a message as:
"Directory 'D:\a\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build 'Ca App artifact'".

May I know why I am not getting the artifacts?

Is it something related to code structure in the azure repository which has to be in a specific way. My "Bin" folder and solution file, both are at the root level of the repo. 
I am also using the same pipeline and same parameters for another project and it is building the artifacts in the packaged format automatically, but over there, the solution file is at the parent level, but the bin folder is at the second level,i.e., at the parent level we have a project folder and inside that we have a bin folder.

Also, another thing is that this project was initially build on Visual studio 2008, framework 3.5 but since I am using default hosted agent in Azure DevOps, it doesn't have visual studio 2008 so I have selected visual studio 2013 version.

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: No, not yet....

Comment: I've solved it, so I'll try to help: Try these MS build arguments. Also, you have to show me your release pipeline with arguments, steps and all.

/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"

Comment: Also, please post your publish artifact step.